# MOQ REQUEST.Forms System.Argument Exception

Tags: c#, moq

```
    public void SetupTests()
    {

        moqsession = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>(); 
        moqContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        moqRequest = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        moqContext.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(moqRequest.Object);
        moqContext.Setup(x => x.Session).Returns(moqsession.Object);
        // Create a "fake" form
        formValues = new NameValueCollection
{
    { "HiddenTransactionNumber", "0" }, 
    { "LastName", "Danylko" }                
};

    } 
    public void Test_withModel()
    {

        moqRequest.Setup(r => r.Form).Returns(formValues);

        var forms = moqContext.Object.Request.Form;
        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(forms);

        ControllerContext ctx = new ControllerContext();
        ctx.HttpContext = moqContext.Object;

        var i = new Mock<IController>();
        i.Setup(d => d.FillViewBag());
        var A = new Model();
        A.Tno = Convert.ToInt64(0);
        var controller = new Controller(i.Object);
        controller.ControllerContext = ctx;
        controller.Index(A); 
    }
```

Above is my unit test code to moq Request.Forms. But when i use it getting run time exception as System.Argument. In Controller my code is myRequest.Form["HTN"]

Comment: I do not understand much of what you ask, but if you do `.Form["HTN"]`, shouldn't the `formValues` contain a pair with name `"HTN"`, such as `{ "HTN", "whatever" },`?

Comment: Sorry type corrected below    { "HTN", "0" }, 
    { "LastName", "Danylko" }

Comment: Try `moqContext.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(moqRequest.Object);` instead of `moqContext.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(moqRequest.Object);`